# Can multiple versions of the same package co-exist on the same system?

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

In order to install tmux 2.1, I needed to install `libtinfo5` version 6, I did this by downloading a .deb archive containing `libtinfo5` and installing directly with command:

```
sudo dpkg -i libtinfo5_6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

This satisfied tmux 2.1's dependency and tmux installed ok.
Now I tried to install vnstat using

```
sudo apt-get install vnstat
```

`apt-get` error exited with the following

```
$ sudo apt-get install vnstat
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libncurses5 : Depends: libtinfo5 (= 5.9+20150516-2ubuntu1) but 6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libncursesw5 : Depends: libtinfo5 (= 5.9+20150516-2ubuntu1) but 6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

My understanding has always been that Ubuntu's package management system was capable of installing and managing multiple versions of the same package, for situations exactly like this.  In other words apt/dpkg recognises

- `tmux` needs libtinfo5 - `version 6` to work
- `vnstat` needs libtinfo5 - `version 5` to work

Then apt/dpkg say's *ok, I'll install both versions*.
I can see how certain programs like a system binary, e.g. `bash` or `ls` can only be installed once as most invocations simply say `bash -c "<command>"` and not `bashv.3.2 -c "<command>"`.
So my question is can the package manager install and manage multiple dependencies?, or is this just not possible because, like in the bash example above, most programs make a call to the dependency by the dependencies name without specifying version. In which case the issue is beyond the control of the package manager (i.e. its more of a programming compilation/configuration/organisation issue) and the package manager gives up at that point?

Comment: You should read up on [snap packages](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/04/ubuntu-16-04-lts-snap-packages).

Comment: You might even be able to build your own snaps for `tmux` and `vnstat` yourself, if they haven't already been built. You do need 16.04 though. https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/build-apps/

Comment: @Zacharee1 thanks for the link. I totally see why the Snaps system is necessary now. The PHP community had the same issue where `PEAR/PECL` is analogous `apt/dpkg` and `Snaps` is analogous to [composer](https://getcomposer.org/)

Comment: @Zacharee1 The newer version of tmux is also already in Ubuntu 16.04. If one wants it on 14.04, it would probably be better to just rebuild the source package from 16.04, or request a backport of the new version, to the backports archive for 14.04.

Comment: But what about all the packages that are managed my "alternatives". Java is an example, and you can have many versions of it. Python is another one, not managed by "alternatives" but by other means: Python3 and Python2 are considered different languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not possible to have two versions of the same *package*, because there will be conflicting files. If a *library* is capable of being installed in two different versions at the same time is a different matter. If you're brave, you could get the source code for one version and see if you can install that to a different directory. **This could very well mess up your system in nasty ways.** It could also just plain not work. Dpkg won't be satisfied, so you'll have to get the source for one of the programs and compile that too. But bear in mind that **once you start compiling programs yourself, you can cause yourself all kinds of problems.**

Comment: Thanks, so basically you are saying I would need to compile from source (most likely independent of the package manager) and mostly self contained in its own monolithic directory - not following the [linux file system hierarchy]( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) then use a local instance of the library /dependency , and modify the source to include this local library, not the system library. At which point I, as you say *once you start compiling programs yourself, you can cause yourself all kinds of problems.*

Comment: That's exactly right. I'm afraid you've been caught in the middle of dependency hell. Usually in cases like yours where different programs depend on different versions of the library, the different versions of the library are shipped as different packages. A good example is libjpeg: there's a libjpeg8, libjpeg9, and libjpeg62. But that is an issue for the package maintainer.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not have different versions of the same package installed at the same time.  Usually dependencies are expressed as *at least* version X.  For packages that are all built from the same source however, the dependency is often exact.  This is what you have run into.  libncurses5 and libtinfo5 are both built from the ncurses source package.  If you want to upgrade one of the packages built from this source, you must upgrade all of them, so you simply need to get and install the same version of the other packages built from this source, so they are all on the same version.

Comment: thanks, yes running tmux 2.1 wasn't critical for me, so I was able to fix this issue by simply removing tmux 2.1 with `dpkg --force-all` then use `apt` to downgrade back to version 5.xx of libtinfo5, and install the distro provided tmux. But this issue was trivial what I was really interested to know about is the fact that two packages can't co-exist within Ubuntu's package managed ecosystem. This obviously has major consequences, but also explains so many issues and comments etc that previously didn't make sense!

Comment: @the_velour_fog, note that some packages ( mostly libraries, bug gcc is usually an application that does this ) are given a new name and store their files in a different place so that you can install two versions at the same time.  This is mostly done when a library makes a change that is not backward compatible.  In that case you might see a "libfoo4" whose version is 4.5.6, and a "libfoo5" package, whose version is 5.1.2, and you can have both installed so that packages that need the older, incompatible version of the library can still get it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same case where I needed to have both PacketTracer 8.1.1 and 8.2.0. Although it was not possible to have both of them with `sudo dkpg -i CiscoPacketTracer_820_Ubuntu_64bit.deb` since the install flag `-i` will always do an override, extracting both of them to custom directories and creating the start scripts myself solved the issue and allowed me to have two different versions of the applications.

Supposing I have these these two versions of PacketTracer that I want to use at the same time:

- `CiscoPacketTracer_811_Ubuntu_64bit.deb`
- `CiscoPacketTracer_820_Ubuntu_64bit.deb`

To keep it organized, I started by creating a custom directory in `/opt` and changing the ownership of it to my user

```bash
sudo mkdir /opt/packettracer
sudo chown sina:sina /opt/packettracer
```

The trick is to extract the content of the `.deb` archives and NOT DO AN INSTALL. You can easily achieve that with

```bash
dpkg -x CiscoPacketTracer_811_Ubuntu_64bit.deb /opt/packettracer/811
dpkg -x CiscoPacketTracer_820_Ubuntu_64bit.deb /opt/packettracer/820
```

Usually, you can directly run the executable but that might not always be the case and you might run into some errors, especially when it comes to installing dependencies. One quick workaround I did is to install one of the packages with `sudo gdebi CiscoPacketTracer_811_Ubuntu_64bit.deb` which will gives me the dependencies, but then I removed the installed PacketTracer with `sudo dpkg -r packettracer`. I still had the dependencies however.

You can also run into a use-case specific issue where the library has a wrapper script that it calls. I can't talk about every use case, but for PacketTracer for example I ended up creating a `start.sh` script at the `/opt/packettracer` directory that accepts the directory of the version I want to run.

I can then directly run both versions with

```bash
/opt/packettracer/start.sh 811
/opt/packettracer/start.sh 820
```

For completeness, I found the initial script by doing a classic installation with `dkpg -i` then typing `which packettracer`. I then took the script and modified it into the following:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ! -d $1 ]]; then
        echo "Cannot start packettracer. Invalid directory for first argument! $1";
        exit 1;
fi;

echo "Custom Script: Starting Packet Tracer $1"
PREFIX=/opt/packettracer/$1

PTDIR=$PREFIX/opt/pt

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PREFIX/opt/pt/bin
pushd $PREFIX/opt/pt/bin > /dev/null
$PREFIX/opt/pt/bin/PacketTracer "$@" > /dev/null 2>&1
popd > /dev/null
```

Comment: This was already answered and the answer is a clear NO. Your one example which is not what was asked about might be an exception. The conflicting module the OP asked about can not have 2 versions as most modules can not.

Comment: @David, that is exactly so when it comes to modules. I stumbled on the issue initially wanting to install two different versions of a software, not a module per-say which is why I just documented my findings in case someone (or future me) has the same problem again.