# Installed app from source but then accidentally deleted source code before uninstalling, can I uninstall the app?

Tags: apt, software-installation, uninstall

I built a program from source then went to pull the code and build again to get a more recent version but my pull wasn't working so I deleted the directory before uninstalling the app (dumb) and now whenever I try to build the app again or try to install via apt it doesn't overwrite the old version. The version I am using is 0.1.12 and the current release is 0.4.0. Am I just screwed here?

Comment: You should actually make sure you didn't just delete or uninstall the app, but also any dependencies it might have come or installed with.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't have any dependencies that aren't also dependencies of a ton of other apps so I didn't install any dependencies just for it.

Comment: If you can install the new version to the same location as the old one, there is usually no issues. Old files will be over written.

Comment: @KnudLarsen The issue is I deleted the old directory so I can overwrite it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to have two versions of the same package, because there will be conflicting files. If a library is capable of being installed in two different versions at the same time is a different matter. If you're brave, you could get the source code for one version and see if you can install that to a different directory. This could very well mess up your system in nasty ways. It could also just plain not work. Dpkg won't be satisfied, so you'll have to get the source for one of the programs and compile that too. But bear in mind that once you start compiling programs yourself, you can cause yourself all kinds of problems.

[Can multiple versions of the same package co-exist on the same system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/758502/can-multiple-versions-of-the-same-package-co-exist-on-the-same-system)

Comment: I've built the most recent version from source and also tried installing via `apt` to see if either would launch instead of the older version and I as able to have my old install, installation from `apt` and installation from source at the same time. This unfortunately didn't change anything though as the old version still launched.